# Flutter - Drag marker and get new position

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, geolocation

In Flutter I have a map that take the device position with help of  [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location). Then i use this position to show marker in Google map with help of [Google Maps Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin.

The code is similar to

```
 child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(lat, lng),
          zoom: 5,
        ),
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(
          <Marker>[
            Marker(
              draggable: true,
              markerId: MarkerId("1"),
              position: LatLng(lat, lng),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
              infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                title: 'Usted está aquí',
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          mapController = controller;
        },
      ))
```

If location plugin fails or take wrong data i need to have the option to reposition this marker. I use *draggable: true* to drag marker, but i need to take the new latitude and longitude for save it in database.

So the question is: Using the draggable how can i get the new latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Marker have **onDragEnd** property. using **onDragEnd** property give new **latitude** and **longitude**.

```
Marker(
          onTap: () {
            print('Tapped');
          },
          draggable: true,
          markerId: MarkerId('Marker'),
          position: LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),
          onDragEnd: ((newPosition) {
            print(newPosition.latitude);
            print(newPosition.longitude);
          }))
```

Comment: how to get the address?

Comment: @MasterpieceMasIcang onDragEnd property will give markers new position.

Comment: can you show me full code, as onDragEnd is not returning any value in my case

Comment: add your code here with github gist link or anyother?

Comment: you have to use geocoding package in order to get address of particular lat lon @MasterpieceMasIcang

Comment: what is the (value) here? position: LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),

Comment: @OsamaMohammed for position parameter you need to pass LatLng for particular marker to place in Google Map. onDragEnd: will give the newPosition of the Marker, after user moving the marker. onDragEnd will give new position only if user trying to move the marker by long pressing the marker.

Comment: yes, but i meant you said (value.lat....) how can i get the value and add the assign it to the position from onDragEnd

Comment: @OsamaMohammed i updated my answer, now your doubt clear?

Comment: still not clear from where came the (value) in this line!!:
 position: LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),

Comment: @OsamaMohammed you need to pass the value for the position parameter for positioning the marker in the Google Map.

Comment: what is the value?

Comment: @OsamaMohammed the value is whatever your marker position is. If you have a marker you have a position....

Answer (score 28):

If you allow me, I would suggest a different approach to this problem. I think in the current version of google maps for Flutter (0.4.0) you don't have a method to get the new position after dragging the marker, so my solution was to use the camera position to move the marker around and then use the current camera position to get the new coordinates.
So in your code, you could do something like this:

```
    child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(lat, lng),
          zoom: 5,
        ),
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(
          <Marker>[
            Marker(
              draggable: true,
              markerId: MarkerId("1"),
              position: LatLng(lat, lng),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
              infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                title: 'Usted está aquí',
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        onCameraMove: ((_position) => _updatePosition(_position)),            
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          mapController = controller;
        },
      ))
```

Then you can set your marker's new state each time the user moves the camera around and use this coordinates for any other purpose you need:

```
void _updatePosition(CameraPosition _position) {
    Position newMarkerPosition = Position(
        latitude: _position.target.latitude,
        longitude: _position.target.longitude);
    Marker marker = markers["1"];

    setState(() {
      markers["1"] = marker.copyWith(
          positionParam: LatLng(newMarkerPosition.latitude, newMarkerPosition.longitude));
    });
  }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: When i press and drag doesn't move the marker, move map, so doesn't is exactly that i want.

Comment: Indeed, this solution moves the marker along with the map camera. It's a different UX than dragging the marker directly, but the result should be the same.

Comment: This works for me. I am using version `^0.5.19+2` and I just had to change this line in `_updatePosition` i.e. instead of `copyWith` i am removing that marker and adding again with new Lat Lng and it gives the desired effect of dragging. `var m = markers.firstWhere(
        (p) => p.markerId == MarkerId('1'),
        orElse: () => null);

    _markers.remove(m);
    _markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('1'),
        position: LatLng(_p.target.latitude, _p.target.longitude),
        draggable: true,
      ),
    );
    setState(() {});`

Comment: I gave upvote for this answer not only because it's good, but also because I'm learning Spanish and I understood the title of InfoWindow :D Thank you for making my day better

Comment: This is better because the pin moves quite a bit when you first pick it up. Better to just slide the map around. No need to make the pin draggable.

Comment: this is a a more modern user experience i love it