# How to get marker latitude and longitude on flutter map?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm using google_maps_flutter package to display the map and I placed a marker so the user can select a location (not the user location any location on the map).
[like this](https://github.com/AbrahemGh1/gitQ/blob/main/Screenshot_1601943632.png)
Now the user can drag the marker where he want ,
my question is

Can I get latitude and longitude for marker after user drag it?

[here is my full code](https://github.com/AbrahemGh1/gitQ/blob/main/Google_map_screen.dart)

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  MapType mapType = MapType.normal;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  LocationServices _locationServices;
  LocationData _locationData;
  CameraPosition _cameraPosition;
  Set<Marker> allMapMarkers;
  Marker userPicker;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _locationServices=Provider.of<LocationServices>(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _locationServices.getLocation().then((LocationData value) => _locationData=value),
      builder:(context,snapshot){
        if(_locationData==null){
         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }else{
          _cameraPosition=CameraPosition(target:LatLng(_locationData.latitude,_locationData.longitude),zoom: 19);
          setupMarkers();   // this set the Lat and Long for marker 
          return SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                  },
                  initialCameraPosition: _cameraPosition,
                  mapType: mapType,
                  compassEnabled: false,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  markers: allMapMarkers,
                ),
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003179/flutter-drag-marker-and-get-new-position

Comment: hi man that real help me ,its seems I'm using Markers in the wrong way, do u know if there is any way to let user select location on map and get the Lat and Long  for that location? @alecsam

Comment: "to select" how? `onDragEnd` (`Marker`) / `onCameraMove` (`GoogleMap`) does not help you?

Comment: @ABCD by "select location", do you mean that you want users to add markers on the position where the user click or tap on the map?

Comment: @alecsam it's work fine and i get what i want, but i was confused that when i use onDragEnd the marker move up a bit immediately without drag it. thank again for help :)

Comment: @jabamataro Hi hope ur doing well :) ,  i'm trying to do the same functionality on Uber map [here is a 7 sec video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NucYzx4_tgg&list=UUVL7DvhLZygk9u5XGkZZwhw) , where is the marker fixed in the center of screen and the map in background after user set the marker on the right location i want to get the lat and Long for that location.

Comment: @ABCD this looks like a place picker widget, there is a feature request on Google's Public Issue Tracker to implement this, you can check it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760). In the mean time, you can build your own place picker with the tutorial [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/location-places-android/index.html#0) which was also mentioned in the feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Marker](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Marker-class.html) from [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin to fetch marker coordinates. It has an `onDrag` property that returns a `LatLng` object that contains coordinates. Use the [onDragEnd](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Marker/onDragEnd.html) property to fetch the coordinates on where the marker has been placed.

```dart
Marker(
  onTap: () {
    debugPrint('Tapped');
  },
  draggable: true,
  markerId: MarkerId('Marker'),
  onDragEnd: ((LatLng newPosition) {
    debugPrint(newPosition.latitude);
    debugPrint(newPosition.longitude);
  }),
)
```